# Not abled to assign old value for ng-select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**html**

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}')" ng-options="item.name group by item.groupName for item in names"
    class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!globalEditor1.isClean()) {
                var r = confirm("You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to proceed ?");
                if (r != true) {
                    oldValue = JSON.parse(oldValue);
                    var oldValueObject = {
                        name: oldValue.name,
                        id: oldValue.id,
                        groupName: oldValue.groupName,
                        lineNumberError : oldValue.lineNumberError,
                        isCompilationError : oldValue.isCompilationError,
                        dataNotMatching : oldValue.dataNotMatching,
                        timeStampNotMatching : oldValue.timeStampNotMatching
                    };
                    $scope.selectedName = oldValueObject;
                    $scope.isPaneShown = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
}
```

So what the js does, it checks if the editor is clear then alerts the user. If the user selects cancel, then the selected value in the ng-select should remain as old value and not the new value which got selected by the user.

But the selected value in ng-select becomes blank when the user clicks `cancel`?
And idea where am I making mistake? Or how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in angularjs an object has an objectHash (named $$objectHash you see that if you debug). It's an identifier, and you can't assign to select an object that isn't in select options.

I write a Plunker with an example. I think this would be helpful to you
https://plnkr.co/edit/YpwhgKSy24kFyYtjRKsv

```
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue){
  // your control, i do simple control because i don't understand exatly what you need
  if(angular.isUndefined(oldValueSelected.id) && oldValue.indexOf('"id"') !== -1){
    oldValueSelected = JSON.parse(oldValue);
  }
}

$scope.clearSelect = function(){
  // check if old value isn't empty
  if(angular.isDefined(oldValueSelected.id)){
    // filter names array and get object of old value
    var possibleOldValues = $filter('filter')($scope.names, {id: oldValueSelected.id}, true);
    if(possibleOldValues.length > 0){
      $scope.selectedName = possibleOldValues[0];
    }
  }
  else{
    $scope.selectedName = {};
  }
}
```